# How to change a custom entity field type - with revisions

Tags: entities

I have a custom content entity for which I needed to change the type of one of its fields.

Following the example on [Updating a base field type](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/update-api/updating-entities-and-fields-in-drupal-8#s-updating-a-base-field-type), I wrote code to update the base entity, which updated perfectly. However, all revisions have null values, including the current revision. Even though the data is stored in the *base_entity* table, it's not stored in the *base_entity_revision* table.

How do I modify `hook_update_N()` to also update the revision tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to updating the main table, you also need to update the revision table, so the following changes should be made:

1. `$id_key = $entity_definition->getKey('id');`

   becomes

   `$id_key = $entity_definition->getKey('id');
   $revision_id_key = $entity_definition->getKey('revision');`
2. `$table_name = $storage->getDataTable() ?: $storage->getBaseTable();`

   becomes

   `$table_name = $storage->getDataTable() ?: $storage->getBaseTable();
   $revision_table_name = $storage->getRevisionDataTable() ?: $storage->getRevisionTable();`
3. `$status_values = $database->select($table_name)
     ->fields($table_name, [$id_key, 'status_field'])
     ->execute()
     ->fetchAllKeyed();`

   becomes

   `$status_values = $database->select($table_name)
     ->fields($table_name, [$id_key, 'status_field'])
     ->execute()
     ->fetchAllKeyed();
   $status_revision_values = $database->select($revision_table_name)
     ->fields($revision_table_name, [$revision_id_key, 'status_field'])
     ->execute()
     ->fetchAllKeyed();`
4. `$database->update($table_name)
     ->fields(['status_field' => NULL])
     ->execute();`

   becomes

   `$database->update($table_name)
     ->fields(['status_field' => NULL])
     ->execute();
   $database->update($revision_table_name)
     ->fields(['status_field' => NULL])
     ->execute();`
5. `foreach ($status_values as $id => $value) {
     $database->update($table_name)
       ->fields(['status_field' => $value])
       ->condition($id_key, $id)
       ->execute();
   }`

   becomes

   `foreach ($status_values as $id => $value) {
     $database->update($table_name)
       ->fields(['status_field' => $value])
       ->condition($id_key, $id)
       ->execute();
   }
   foreach ($status_revision_values as $id => $value) {
   $database->update($revision_table_name)
   ->fields(['status_field' => $value])
   ->condition($revision_id_key, $id)
   ->execute();
   }`